# `dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings.Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead.`

Tags: html, string, numpy, flask, numpy-ndarray

`ValueError: dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings.Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead.`

`@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict_placement():
ans = request.form.get("msg")

```
result = model.predict(np.array([ans]).reshape(-1, 1))`
```

`I'm taking a string input in Html form and getting this error, how to resolve this?`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The data you give for you predict is in the format string, however your model can only deal with numerical data. You should try to do some encoding for your features before passing it to your predict.